# .animate() not working on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to use the animate effect on the scroll associated with hashbang links on the page.

When I use this on a regular website it works perfectly.

As soon as I try to use it on a wordpress site it doesn't animate, it just jumps to the DIV instead of scrolling.

jQ code (Tried placing it in the head, body and footer (makes no difference) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Here are my current versions of JQuery in case there is an issue there?

**jquery.js?ver=1.11.0**

**jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1**

Could it be the order that wordpress is enqueing the scripts?

Any ideas because I'm pulling my hair out here!

Comment: Link to your site to see the problem?

Comment: Well for one after you've done `jQuery.noConflict();` you can no longer use `$`. Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: Juhana, I wasn't using noConflict originally, I just tried that as a last resort as it wasn't working the other way. Thanks though, I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with wrap `(function($){ //your content })(jQuery);`

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 900, 'swing', function(){
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks Joffrey, that works perfectly! I will check this as the correct answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

change to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ // pass $ as an arg here
```

You need to pass `$` as an argument in the ready callback and you don't need to have `jQuery.noConflict();` so remove it.

---

Because wordpress uses `jQuery` instead of `$` so that this wont get conflicted with other libraries which uses `$` as an alias, So you can do two things

1. Just do as suggested above or
2. replace every occurance of `$` with jQuery.

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't aware of that. Very useful info, thanks Jai ;)

Comment: @Grant its okay glad this helped in some way.